# JQuery troubleshooting: I am trying to make my div reverse .slideup()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/GwBuj/1061/

I have no idea why this is not working. I have been stuck on this problem for a while.

HTML:

```
   <div class="step" id="firststep">
         <div class="stepgraphic2">fadjkfjka</div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#firststep').click(function() {

     alert('fjad');                   
     $('.stepgraphic2').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

CSS:
   ​

```
.step{        
    float: left;
    height: 230px;
    width: 230px;
    background-color: #025588;
    margin-top: 115px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}  
.stepgraphic2{  
    background-color:#FFF;
    height: 170px;
    width: 157px;    
}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses Jquery UI methods, include below script(after jquery script is called) and it should work

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

I tried and it worked!

EDIT: To be specific the easing method(Slide down) is included in jquery ui script which you need to reference.

Comment: @Chetan Yes it worked fine in this jsfiddle because JqueryUI library is selected, while it was not selected for original jsfiddle.